# Number of subsets of an array (size n) of size k having difference between maximum and minimum elements at most x

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I came across this question during a test. Given an array of size n find number of subsets of size k having difference between maximum and minimum element at most x.

```
Constraints 1<=a[i],n,k,x<=10^6
Example:n=5 k=3 x=5 a={1,2,3,4,5}
output: 10
```

**My Approach So Far:**
I first sorted the array and considered the greatest element . Now using linear search I found the smallest element whose such that difference is less than or equal to x.

Now if I take that greatest element and selected any k-1 elements between them .Selection process was (index of greatest - index of smallest)C(k-1) and I summed up these.

Complexity is coming around O(nnk). I wasn't stuck but my solution couldn't pass the test cases.

Comment: usually solution is modelled according to the constraint... without those, no one can tell you what is the best solution

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving this and mention where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Mox I've updated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any duplicates in the array?

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal I first sorted the array and considered the greatest element . Now using linear search I found the smallest element whose such that difference is less than or equal to x. Now if I take that greatest element and selected any k-1 elements between them .Selection process was (index of greatest - index of smallest)C(k-1) and I summed up these .Complexity is coming around O(n*n*k) . I wasn''t stuck but my solution couldn't pass the test cases

Comment: @Kaidul Islam yes.

Comment: @ananya, my hint to u, u need to use combination and counting technique  after sorting

Comment: @Mox could you please elaborate I tried combinations for each element which is giving complexity around O(n*n*k) which I think is bad.

Comment: @ananya , im currently on my mobile so i cant really create a proper answer. the first thing u need to do is to do a number freq count using a binary tree which will sort the numbers too, set a start and end iterator for the tree, which make them travel towards each other. so whenever the number from start iterator + end iterator is equals to x, u will need to calculate the number of combinations for the subset that has this 2 numbers as min and max. I hope this give u the direction to the correct solution.

Comment: expected runtime is n log n

Comment: @ananya Your approach is still not clear. I have copy-pasted it in the question details verbatim. Please edit your question details to clarify the method that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. As I understand it, this is what you have so far:

- Sort the array.

  - You don't say how you're doing this, but you can do it in O(*n*) time using a radix sort, so I'll assume O(*n*) time.
- For each element:

  - Count how many other elements are between *E* − *x* and *E* (where *E* is the value of this element). Call the result *m*.

    - You're doing this in worst-case O(*n*) time by using a linear search.
  - Compute <sub>*m*</sub>*C*<sub>*k*−1</sub>.

    - You don't say how you're doing this, but you can precompute this for all possible *m* in O(*n*) time and then just use a constant-time lookup, so I'll assume that's what you're doing.

This approach gives the correct result, and requires worst-case O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time. (You mention that you were getting O(*n*<sup>2</sup>*k*) time; but I don't see any reason for that.)

The major optimization that you seem to be missing is that instead of restarting your linear search for each element, you can resume your linear search from where the previous element's linear search left off. That way, all of your linear searches *put together* will add up to linear time, since they amount to just a single pass over the array. (In other words, your linear searches will have *amortized constant time*.)

This gives us an algorithm in O(*n*) time:

```
sort a
precompute nCr(m, k - 1) for all m in (0 .. n-1)
set total_num_subsets := 0
set min_element_index := 0
for max_element_index in 0 .. n-1 do:
    while a[min_element_index] + x < a[max_element_index] do:
        set min_element_index := min_element_index + 1
    set num_eligible_elements := max_element_index - min_element_index
    set num_subsets := nCr(num_eligible_elements, k - 1)
    set total_num_subsets := total_num_subsets + num_subsets
```

(There are some additional minor optimizations we can do — for example, we can start the `max_element_index` iteration at `k` rather than `0`, and we can use memoization rather than precomputation to avoid computing <sub>*m*</sub>*C*<sub>*k*−1</sub> for larger values of *m* than we actually end up needing — but they don't change the algorithmic complexity.)

Comment: I was calculating nCr in O(n*r) time. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you.

1. First to get subset of length k recursively .
2. If current length is equal to k

   2.1 then store in auxiliary array **a** with length of k

   2.2 Sort it in k*log(k)

   2.3 get absolute difference between first and last element.(As first is minimum and last is maximum)

   2.4 check difference is less than equal to 4 then count++;

   ```
    public class AllSubSetOfSizeK 
      {

      static int count=0; 
     public void get_SubSet(int[] A, int k, int start_index, int curr_Len,  boolean[] used)


     {

   int a[]=new int[k];
   int l=0;

   if (curr_Len == k) {
       for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
           if (used[i] == true) {
               a[l++]=A[i];
           }
       }
       Arrays.sort(a);//To Sort the Array of k length
       if(Math.abs(a[0]-a[k-1])<=4);
           count++;
       return;
   }
   if (start_index == A.length) {
       return;
   }

   used[start_index] = true;
   get_SubSet(A, k, start_index + 1, curr_Len + 1, used);

   used[start_index] = false;
   get_SubSet(A, k, start_index + 1, curr_Len, used);

   }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
       int A[] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
        boolean[] B = new boolean[A.length];
        AllSubSetOfSizeK obj = new AllSubSetOfSizeK();
       obj.get_SubSet(A, 3, 0, 0, B);
       System.out.println(count);

     }

   }
   ```